# Graph regular of degree 0, does Line graph exist?

Tags: graph-theory

If a graph is regular of degree 0, does a Line graph exist for it?

Comment: Is a regular graph with degree zero a discrete set?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it's just the graph with no vertices - its vertex set is the empty set and its edge set is the empty set. (Sometimes called the *null* graph.)

Comment: Awesome thanks was just making sure I had included the 0 deg case for a proof